# Get text only within parenthesis from a file in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, parsing

I have a large log file I need to sort, I want to extract the text between parentheses. The format is something like this:

```
<@44541545451865156> (example#6144) has left the server!
```

How would I go about extracting "example#6144"?

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. People ask questions like this here often enough. These questions are easy to answer and, more importantly, lend themselves to answers that lead OP to learn something he didn't know before.

Comment: (When I commented earlier, the reason given to close was *off topic,* which I disagreed. *Duplicate* is a better reason.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `sed` should work here:

`sed -E -n 's/.*\((.*)\).*$/\1/p' file_name`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

Assuming you always have only one lexeme in parentheses, you can use `bash` parameter expansion:

```
while read t; do echo $(t=${t#*(}; echo ${t%)*}); done <logfile
```

The first substitution: `${t#*(}` cuts off everything up and including the left parenthesis, leaving you with `example#6144) has left the server!`; the second one: `${t%)*}` cuts off the right parenthesis and everything after that.

Alternatively, you can also use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[)(]' '{print $2}' logfile
```

`-F'[)(]'` tells `awk` to use either parenthesis as the field delimiter, so it splits the input string into three tokens: `<@44541545451865156>`, `example#6144`, and `has left the server!`; then `{print $2}` instructs it to print the second token.

`cut` would also do:

```
cut -d'(' -f 2 logfile | cut -d')' -f 1
```

Comment: You need to quote the thing you `echo`, otherwise the shell will perform another round of whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^.*(\([^()]*\)).*$/\1/' <logfile
```

The `/^.*(\([^()]*\)).*$/` is a *regular expression* or *regex.* Regexes are hard to read until you get used to them, but are most useful for extracting text by pattern, as you are doing here.

Comment: This will print in full any lines which do not contain the pattern.

Comment: @tripleee: true enough. Well, it looks as though other answerers have this covered, so I'll just upvote theirs. Thanks.